# C++ error "not declared in scope" 2nd week of programming,

Tags: c++

This is my first week of programming and this project is due tomorrow.  Here is the important part of the code:

```
char Keep_going;
   
cout << "What would you like to do? 'M' for menu or 'Q' for quit \n" ;
cin >> Keep_going ;

if ( Keep_going == M )
{
cout << "Returning to menu \n" ;    
}

if ( Keep_going == Q )
{
choice = -1;    
}  


}while ( choice > 0 ) ;

system ("pause");
return 0;
```

I keep getting the error:

> 'M' was not declared in this scope
>
> 'Q' was not declared in this scope

can someone help me fix this?

Comment: `M` references a symbol named `M` (like `int M;` or `double M;` or `void M(int f);`) but you want the character `M` which you need to express as `'M'`.

Comment: This *cannot* be your entire program -- where is `main`, where are the braces? Without those you'd get even more errors. Anyway, the thing you are looking for is you are comparing a variable to a variable. Change `M` to the one-character constant `'M'`, and the same for `Q`.

Comment: Wow it worked. thanks everyone, i kinda feel stupid now lol.

Comment: @Jongware Btw thats not my entire code, i would post it if i knew how

Answer (score 1):

By simply using the letter Q and M without quotes the compiler treats them as variables. Simply surrounding Q and M with quotes should fix your problem. e.g 'Q'

Answer (score 1):

The symbols M and Q are going to look to the cpp compiler like variables.  You want to change to `'M'`, and `'Q'`, which are literal characters.  Also it is a good idea for comparisons to put the constant on the left (in case you mistype `==` as `=)`

```
    char Keep_going;

    cout << "What would you like to do? 'M' for menu or 'Q' for quit \n" ;
    cin >> Keep_going ;

    if ( 'M' == Keep_going )
    {
    cout << "Returning to menu \n";
    }
    else if ( 'Q' == Keep_going )
    {
    choice = -1;    
    }  
}while ( (choice > 0) ) ;

system ("pause");
return 0;
```

*Good luck!*